# Does Spring data Neo4j support schema-less property?

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

The nosql database has schema-less property, so we could add any fields/properties to nodes or relationship. But If I use spring data as the framework, I have to pre-define the field of nodes and relationship object. It seem Spring data Neo4j not support inserting field dynamically...Is it true?

Answer (score 0):

It most definitely supports dynamically inserting fields.

Just update your POJOs with the appropriate fields/annotations, run it, and enjoy the magic!

To recap:

1. Update your POJOs whenever you need with whatever fields and annotations.
2. Run your project.
3. Profit.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But this method must update the code. Do there exist any method to insert fields dynamically without updating pojo? Thanks:)

Comment: Why would you want to use SDN, then?

Comment: I am not sure what is your meaning? I want to design a system which users may dynamically insert data with new properties to neo4j. If it is impossible to add new properties dynamically, I will save the new properties in MongoDB and keep relationship in Neo4j.

Comment: I suppose you'd lose the usage of POJOs, then, or at least would have to come up with your own clever wrapper. Michael Hunger may be able to comment.

Comment: I am facing the same requirement, did you actually end up combining with mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Data Neo4j version 3, then [DynamicProperties](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-neo4j/3.0.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/fieldaccess/DynamicProperties.html) will probably fulfill your needs.

However, in version 4 it has not yet been implemented see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29298399/364401).